# Hibernate, getting duplicate values

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, jbpm, hibernate-criteria

I am writing a very simple query, but I am getting duplicate values for some reason.

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(ProcessInstance.class, "p")
        .add(Restrictions.isNull("end"));
@Cleanup ScrollableResults sr = cr.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);

while (sr.next()) {
    pi = (ProcessInstance) sr.get(0);
    String id = pi.getId(); //Getting duplicate values
}
```

The `pi.getId()` returns duplicate values. ie: `*9,9,10,10,11,11 etc*`

However, running this query directly in mysql

```
SELECT * FROM JBPM_PROCESSINSTANCE J where J.END_ IS NULL
```

Does not return duplicate values.

Can anyone spot what is wrong?

Comment: without your mapping it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The fast workarround would be to use a Distinct Root Entity Result Transformer.

```
...
crit.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
List unique = crit.List();
...
```

But this is only a workarround.

I ques the problem belongs to your mapping. If there is any eager loaded 1:n relationship from ProcessInstance to something else (call it X), and there are several (n) X for one ProcessInstance, the you will get several ProcessInstance items (n) in the result list for a single ProcessInstance. -- If this is realy the cause, than the workarround is not just a workarround, then it would be the solution.

Comment: Yes this is right. We changed mapping to be fetch eager. Thanks

Comment: This didn't help. We still get duplicates. Does the resultTransformer only work with List()? We are using scroll.

Comment: You understand me wrong: the problem can occure if the relation IS fetched egger - change it to lazy.

Comment: I cannot change it to lazy. We must have eager because of another bug in jbpm/seam. Is there some other workaround? I can also report that your solution worked using `list()`. However, I am looking for a solution using `scroll`

Comment: Is this case the result transtransformer is the only solution i know - But it needs to load all entites first, and this is why scroll does not work.

Comment: The only hack I know to implemnt scolling like you need, is to fetch only the IDs with the first query using DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY, and then load the real entities with an second Scrollable query by its ID's -- But if this increase your performance strongly depends on your use case.

Comment: I have same problem but this solution doesn't help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127626/criteria-distinct-root-entity-doesnt-prevent-duplicated-objects

Answer (score 2):

I encouter the same problem as you..

This is how I solve it.

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(ProcessInstance.class, "p")
        .add(Restrictions.isNull("end")).setProjection("id")
```

this will returns all the ID that satisfy all your criteria.

there after you use `In` restrictions and perform `CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY`.

You will be able to scroll your result in 2nd criteria.. I hope this help.